# problems with pygame.event and pygame.draw

Tags: pygame

I am trying to make two 8*8 screens. In one i want pygame to draw circles and in the other one three rectangles.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1063,501))

pygame.draw.line(screen,(255,255,255),(0,0),(0,500))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (0,0),(500,0))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (500,0),(500,500))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (500,500),(0,500))
for i in range(8):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (0,i*62.5+62.5),(500,i*62.5+62.5))
for i in range(8):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (i*62.5+62.5,0),(i*62.5+62.5,500))


pygame.draw.line(screen,(255,255,255),(562,0),(562,500))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (562,0),(1062,0))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (1062,0),(1062,500))
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (1062,500),(500,500))

for i in range(8):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (562,i*62.5+62.5),(1062,i*62.5+62.5))
for i in range(8):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (562 + i*62.5+62.5,0),(562+i*62.5+62.5,500))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x  = int(pos[0])
            y  = int(pos[1]) 
            x1 = int(pos[0]//62.5)
            y1 = int(pos[1]//62.5)
            x2 = int(x1*62.5+62.5/2)
            y2 = int(y1*62.5+62.5/2)
            print(x2,' ',y2)
            if x >563:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (x2, y2), 10, 0)
                print(x1-8,' ',y1+1)

while True:
    if event.type == KEYDOWN :
        if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.display.update()
        if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.display.update()
        if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_3:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-(27+62.5), y2-27, 55, 55))
            pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.update()
```

I have no idea whats the problem with this I am trying to make two 8*8 screens. In one i want pygame to draw circles and in the other one three rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 while loops, changing it to this works:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x  = int(pos[0])
            y  = int(pos[1])
            x1 = int(pos[0]//62.5)
            y1 = int(pos[1]//62.5)
            x2 = int(x1*62.5+62.5/2)
            y2 = int(y1*62.5+62.5/2)
            print(x2,' ',y2)
            if x >563:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (x2, y2), 10, 0)
            print(x1-8,' ',y1+1)


        if event.type == KEYDOWN :
            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))

            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_2:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))

            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_3:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-(27+62.5), y2-27, 55, 55))

    pygame.display.update()
```

However, unless you click somewhere in the window before you press 1, 2 or 3, you'll get an error as `x` is defined inside the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event. To fix this and draw 1, 2 or 3 squares under the mouse pointer without clicking inside the window move the `pos` declaration out of the event loop:

```
while True:

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x  = int(pos[0])
    y  = int(pos[1])
    x1 = int(pos[0]//62.5)
    y1 = int(pos[1]//62.5)
    x2 = int(x1*62.5+62.5/2)
    y2 = int(y1*62.5+62.5/2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(x2,' ',y2)
            if x >563:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (x2, y2), 10, 0)
                print(x1-8,' ',y1+1)


        if event.type == KEYDOWN :
            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))

            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_2:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))

            if x < 531 and event. key == pygame.K_3:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-27, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2+35, y2-27, 55, 55))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (x2-(27+62.5), y2-27, 55, 55))

    pygame.display.update()
```